# How to populate text input type based on select input type?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am new to web development. I want to know how to populate text input type based on select drop down. Say I am selecting branch and I want its employee number automatically in text box. Can it be done using AJAX? If yes how? I want employee number from MySQL database. Plus I want to display its arrival time in other text input from same MySQL table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are selecting a branch or an employee and want the person's number to show in the text input?

Comment: Can it be done? Yes, probably; but, with no information to represent your situation, how it can done is impossible to say.

Comment: Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nafnR/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this surely can be done with JQuery & Ajax. So your code will look something like

```
$(document).on("change","#dropDownSelector", function(){

var changedVal = $("#dropDownSelector").val();

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'actionUrl', //logic for getting the data based on dropdown valur from db
            data: { 
                "value": changedVal,

            },
            beforeSend:function (){
                //Do something before request is sent like showing loading image
            },
            success:function (data){
                //Success . Use the data and show it on ui
            },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // failed request; give feedback to user

          },
          complete:function (){
                //Do something after request is complete.   
          }
        });
```

You still need to create the url and action for that based on the server side language and database you are working on. But overall your javascript code should follow this.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do so directly with JavaScript, but you might want to consider jQuery's change method (http://api.jquery.com/change/).  When the menu is changed, you update the input.

```
$( "#yourMenu" ).change(function() {
    $.get("yourServerScript.php", {selectedID:$(this).val()}, function( data ) {
        $("yourInput").val(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only PHP and mysql. Make the titles of your select box to be the employee numbers and then use that to populate the text boxes:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option class='branch' title='$row[employee_number]' value = '$row[branch]'>$row[branch]</option>";
}
```

And then using jQuery:

```
$('.branch').change(function(event) {
    $('#employee').val($(this).attr('title'));
}
```

Assuming the text input has an id attribute with 'employee' as value.